# Sending Bulk Message to Twilio "Bad Request"

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio

We are sending bulk SMS using twilio for eg. 50 SMS from our server which is very fast, it return me bad request message for some requests, means arround 2 -3 requests and sends other around 47 messages successfully. When connect the same database to my local server or to dev server which is slow then it sends all requests successfully.

I am not sure but i thought that sending too nanny request  very fast to twilio cause the issue. Can anybody know why i get error "Bad Request" on server that is very fast and not to server that is a bit slow on same data.

Comment: what is the sms limit? Are you using Rest APi in asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

If you are getting a 400 Bad Request response from Twilio its likely that included in that response is some detail about what went wrong.

If you are using our .NET helper library you can check the RestException property for the error message:

```
message = client.SendMessage("5555555555","5555555555","asdasd");
if (message.RestException != null) { /* something broke */ }
```

Or you can examine the body of the failing requests using an HTTP proxy tool like Fiddler.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Actually issue was user reply with "STOP". I get the proper error code when test the number with Twilio test environment on dev tool section